# 'Apex request count has exceeded limit' error in Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, slack

I got the following error: `Error Occurred During Flow "Send Slack Messages": Apex request count has exceeded limit.`

The "Send Slack Messages" flow is a custom flow that simply loops through a collection of an Apex-defined type SlackMessage and sends them using the [*Send Slack Message* action from *Flow Core Actions for Slack*](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_slack_send_message.htm&type=5).

[image]

The flow is being called from an Apex queueable, something like this:

```java
public class SlackMessageSenderWithFlow implements SlackMessageSender {

    private static final String FLOW_SEND_SLACK_MESSAGE = 'Send_Slack_Messages';

    public void send(List<SlackMessage> messages) {
        Flow.Interview.createInterview(FLOW_SEND_SLACK_MESSAGE, new Map<String, Object> {
                'vc_SlackMessages' => messages
        }).start();
    }
}
```

```java
public class AQueueable implements Queueable {

    public void execute(QueueableContext ctx) {
        // ...
        sender.send(messages);
    }
}
```

The error is thrown with just 2 messages, so it's not a callout limit related error.

Is this error due to some kind of limitation of Salesforce flows?
The [documentation about the Flow.Interview class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/flow_interview_class.htm) doesn't state any limitations regarding this situation. I also have not been able to find any information about this error message.

Comment: Hmm -- try putting a Pause element after each Send Slack Message action (hopefully there's a better answer than this). I presume from debug that the Send Slack Message action doesn't trigger other automation that is where the limit breach occurs. You could also loop through each `message` by calling the `Flow.Interview` `start()` once per `message`

Comment: I tried with just 1 message, and the same error occurs. I think it must be something related to the way the action is called (a queueable that executes a Flow, that runs a Slack action).
I tried to use `SlackMessageSenderWithFlow` to send multiple messages (50) from the developer console, and it works perfectly.

Comment: does your queueable execute() do anything other than invoke a FlowInterview start()?